# jQuery validate different subset of fields if radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validate plugin to validate form input. The problem I have run into is that I have a radio button group that hides and shows different fields based on the radio button selected.

How can I validate the subset of fields that are hidden and shown depending on what radio button option is selected.

Thanks

Comment: i think u want `ignore: ":hidden"` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `depends` rule:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
   rules: {
      contact: {
         required: {
            depends: function(element) {
               return $("#myCheckbox:checked");
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

This example sets the `contact` field to only be required is the `#myCheckbox` field is checked.